# How to scrape this piece of HTML with BS

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape following kind of HTML in BeautifulSoup.

```
<div …. > <div…..>
<div class=“class1">Jill</div> <div class=“class2">50</div>
<div class=“class1">Jane</div>
<div class=“class1">Joe</div>  <div class=“class2">12</div>
</div></div>
```

Not every person has a second item to scrape so things like soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": “class2"}) will not work correctly (it will return both 50 and 12 but the 12 is not connected with the right person)

Wanted result (in variables):

`Jill   50
 Jane
 Joe    12`

Comment: Yes find_all() will return all element having classname `class2`.If you use find() it will return 1st match.However not clear what is your expected out put??I guess you need to claas2 value wrt username of class1?

Comment: I've updated the question with the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You could get all name('class1') elements and check if they have a corresponding age('class2') element.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class='parent'>
    <div class="class1">Jill</div> <div class="class2">50</div>
    <div class="class1">Jane</div>
    <div class="class1">Joe</div> <div class="class2">12</div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

name_tags = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'class1'})

name_age_pairs = []

# Iterate through all 'class1' elements and see if the next sibling is 'class2'
for name_tag in name_tags:
    name_next_div = name_tag.find_next('div')
    age = None
    if 'class2' in name_next_div['class']:
        age = int(name_next_div.string)
    name_age_pairs.append((name_tag.string, age))

print(name_age_pairs)
```

`name_age_pairs` will contain:

```
[('Jill', 50), ('Jane', None), ('Joe', 12)]
```

Where 'None' means there is no age associated with the second person.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pairs = []
for div in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'class1'}):
    name = div.text
    item = ''
    tmp = div.find_next('div')
    if 'class2' in tmp['class']:
        item = tmp.text
    pairs.append([name, item])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally used. Works for multiple values and spaces inside class names.

```
# default values for vars
Item1 = Item2 = Item3 = ""

for item in soup.find_all('div'):

    # convert to str for comparison reasons
    strItem = str(item)

    if strItem.find("class1") > 0 and item.string != None:

        if Item1 != "": # if you have None as default change this
            print(Item1, Item2, Item3) # or make list, dict, json, csv, sql......

        Item2 = Item3 = "" # default values for vars
        Item1 = item.string

    elif strItem.find("class2") > 0 and item.string != None:
        Item2 = item.string

    elif strItem.find("class3") > 0 and item.string != None:
        Item3 = item.string

    # and so on....

# don't forget to process the last one...
print(Item1, Item2, Item3) # # or make list, dict, json, csv, sql......
```